# Use Spark with Spark-cassandra-connector query materialized views

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

I'm using Cassandra v. 3.2.1 and created a materialized view.
Also I have a Spark program where I would like to query the view but receiving following exception:

```
java.io.IOException: Couldn't find MyNamespace.MyView or any similarly named keyspace and table pairs
```

Does the connector has support for materialized views?

Comment: According to the compatibility matrix, if you're using the connector version 1.5, it is pulling the Java driver version 3.0.0 so it should normally support MV: https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector#version-compatibility

Comment: @doanduyhai I also checked in version 3.0.2, and it is not working.

Answer (score 1):

I've had a look into the source code of the spark-connector master, support for materialized view is not there yet so I created this JIRA for follow up: https://datastax-oss.atlassian.net/browse/SPARKC-326